# Angular 2/4/5 - Онлайн просмотр Excel, Word

Tags: javascript, excel, angular2, typescript, ms-word

Существуют ли библиотеки или модули для Angular 2/4/5, которые позволяют просмотреть Excel или Word файл в онлайн (возможность редактирования документа не важна, но если будет - то супер)?